# An event which will be raised when the last of item of a window is rendered

Tags: wpf, window, switching

In my wpf application I am switching from one window(Window A) to another window(Window B) rapidly. The window to which I am switching to has some grid which gets populated using the values from database. I am seeing a delay of 30-60 secs before the second window to render. during this 60 secs the window is going blank and the desktop is visible. To circumvent this problem i am planning to hide the Window A only when the last control of the Window B is rendered. Is there any event to help me  on this?

Comment: What takes so much time for page initialization? Data or tricky design)?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't wait and then display the window, but rather gather the data asynchronously (e.g. via BackgroundWorker). 
Over the dataGrid you could display a Loading Adorner to show that data is still being gathered in the background.

Here's a cool example:
http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/wpf-overlays-or-better-adorner/